# Java NullPointerException while using array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

Why do I get a NullPointerException, when I try to execute the method "temperaturEingeben"?
I hope you can understand my code because it´s in German.

```
public class Temperaturanzeige{                                 
    private int[] temperatur;                                   

    public Temperaturanzeige(){                                 
        int[] temperatur=new int[24];                           
        for(int i=0; i<temperatur.length;i++){                  
            temperatur[i]=-100;
        }

    }

    public void temperaturEingeben(int tempNeu,int tageszeit){
        temperatur[tageszeit]=tempNeu;
    }

}
```

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Are you sure it's NullPointerException and not IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: You never set the field `temperatur` anywhere. Yeah, there is a local variable with the same name, but that only shadows the field.

Comment: I would be useful if you show the full code, where you call the `Temperaturanzeige` object and call the `temperaturEingeben()` function that gives you the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn There is probably a dupe but that one is too generic to be of use. I scanned the topmost 3 answers and those didn't contain the issue.

Comment: Then close if for small error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int[] temperatur=new int[24];
```

Creates a new variable, remove the `int[]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You create a new variable in the constructor instead of assign a variable. Change this:

```
int[] temperatur=new int[24];
```

to this:

```
this.temperatur = new int[24];
```